# How can I convert from Pandas DataFrame to TimeSeries?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like this. How can I create a Time Series from this data frame??

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=True)
df.tail()
```

The output is what you see below.

I tried pd.Series(df). However I get this error: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 729.

[image]

The data I am reading in looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please put real code in the question instead of pictures in order to reproduce your question.

Comment: You can't construct a Series from a df they are fundamentally different, 1 is 1 dimensional the other is 2 dimensional it looks like all you want is to just set the index to your 'ds' column like Fabio's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `df` be your dataframe, you can first read it and parse dates with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv',parse_dates=['ds'])
```

then you can set its index to get the time as index with:

```
df = df.set_index('ds')
```

and then proceed. It depends on your needs but you should now have a dataframe ready for a time-series analysis.

EDIT:

I tried to reproduce your sample dataframe:

```
city,ds,bookings
City_1,2013-01-01,55
City_2,2013-01-02,56
```

And applied the above method it returns:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv',parse_dates=['ds'])
df = df.set_index('ds')
```

which returns:

```
              city  bookings
ds                          
2013-01-01  City_1        55
2013-01-02  City_2        56
```

Comment: I get the following error after following your instructions: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 729. I tried pd.Series(df) after.

Comment: Please post some real data, have you got problems in reading the dataframe from a file? It might depend on the separator etc., and then try to set the column with dates in `parse_dates` instead of setting it to `True`.

Comment: Added some real data. Thanks for your help. I don't think I am having problems reading in the data.I tried setting parse_dates = ['ds'] and I got the same error. Is it maybe because my data frame has the additional city column that can't fit in a time series?

Comment: I added your test case in the answer. If the format is the one you post you should not having problems in reading the file.

Comment: Hmm what is the code you use to go from the data frame to the series? After setting the index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92606/discussion-between-fabio-and-pr338).